# Swift: Network-Request at AppStart in AppDelegate - CompletionHandler in ViewController?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, networking, request, completionhandler

my app is based on a TabBarController with 4 ViewControllers. All 4 of them are dependent of the same data. This is why I would like to load the data at the App start in the AppDelegate.

However, how does the ViewController know, that the request is completed? For example, if there is an error (e.g. no internet connection), how do I pass this error to any of these 4 ViewController to present an alert?

Comment: Use NSNotificatioCenter to post a notification (called "DataIsReady") when your data is ready, another notification (e.g. called "ErrorOccurs") when there is error, all view controllers observe the notifications and handle them.

Answer (score 0):

Use NotificationCenter to implement (Swift 3 code):

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static var RequestCompleted = Notification.Name(rawValue: "MyRequestIsCompleted")
    static var RequestError = Notification.Name(rawValue: "MyRequestError")
}

class DataRequest {

    func request() {

        // if there is error:
        let error = NSError(domain: "Error Sample", code: 0, userInfo: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .RequestError, object: error)

        // if the request is completed
        let data = "your data is here"
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .RequestCompleted, object: data)

    }

}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(requestCompleted(_:)), name: .RequestCompleted, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(requestError(_:)), name: .RequestError, object: nil)

    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    func requestCompleted(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let obj = notification.object {
            print(obj)
        }
    }

    func requestError(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let obj = notification.object {
            print(obj)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If your DataRequest class is a singleton object, you can save the request data to a iVar and don't need to pass into the post call (so in the handler, the obj will be empty but you can access it from the singleton class)